# Symfony twig render component with generated urls for subdomains as it was on main domain

Tags: php, twig, subdomain, symfony

I have a twig template of navigation and footer with links to main page.

```
{{ url("help") }} -> https://main.com/help
```

I am rendering them on subdomain from same codebase. But I do not want to have links to subdomain page.

```
{{ url("help") }} -> https://subdomain.com/help //but I need https://main.com/help
```

How can I set domain for template or what is the optimal solution, other then duplicating templates and setting urls directly?

Comment: `url()` is your own twig extension ?

Comment: url() is symfony twig extension probably best solution would be to create twig extension for this or do you have any idea how to solve our test/dev/local other domains problem.

Comment: either you do your own twig extension, either you use `app.request.attributes` in twig to get the request attributes and construct your url as you want

Comment: Why not using `path()` and the relative route ?

Comment: If I use path() I would stay on the subdomain but I want to transfer visitors from subdomain to main domain.

Comment: Can't you write a custom twig extension that basically does `mainDomain + path()` (where mainDomain is retrieved from a config)?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to  the party but this can be achieved by defining the host for the 'help'-route in the controller like so:

```
#[Route('/help', name: 'help', host: '%domain%')]
```

`%domain%` is a env-variable that can be defined flexibly. This way the url function can create the link for the right domain.

Maybe this could still help someone who stumbles upon this problem!